# Atributo data no muestra el texto completo del valor en base de datos

Tags: javascript, select, data, dataset

tengo problema al mostrar el contenido completo de un atributo data-, el valor es obtenido de la base de datos (mysql) este se guarda en data-articulo pero al mostrarlo en la consola no muestra el texto completo por ejemplo:

'Artículos para el hogar'  --------------> este es el nombre completo como debería.

el data en consola solo agrega 'Artículos', e ignora el 'para el hogar'

```
case 'selectArticulo':
        $rspta=$departamento->select3();
        //echo '<option value="0">seleccione...</option>';
        while ($reg=$rspta->fetch_object()) {
            echo '<option value=' . $reg->id_articulo .' data-descripcion='. $reg->descripcion .' data-partida='. $reg->partida .' data-unidad='. $reg->unidad_medida .' data-importe='. $reg->importe .'>'.$reg->objeto_gasto.'</option>';
        }
        break;
```

Agradecería su ayuda e intentado todo pero parece que solo toma la primer palabra de una descripción completa

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/523705/edit) para agregar el código con el que creas los elementos HTML, aunque supongo que solo te falta encerrar los valores entre comillas.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: @Triby en efecto era eso revise todo menos eso muchas gracias